# Android Recyclerview not remeasuring its height

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

My application has a lot of nested recycler views , In one of those I have a layout which holds an image and a textview like this.

[image]

The text view is an indicator which would disappear when the user opens that specific course.
And it would become something like this :

[image]

Since the indicator is present only on some of the courses , the indicator might disappear (view.gone) and appear (view.visible) on certain conditions.
This is the recyclerview code that holds these courses.

```
                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/rv_video_packs"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_16dp"
                    android:clipToPadding="false"
                    android:paddingEnd="16dp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/rv_continue_watching" />
```

Notice that the recycler view is a wrap content.

When there is a case of multiple courses , some courses might not contain the new video indicator. And if those courses with no indicator is present on the screen then the recyclerview would wrap its height to only hold on to the course image , something like this.

[image]

but the issue is , when we scroll horizontally , some courses might contain the indicator , meaning that the recyclerview should increase its height accordingly to accommodate the indicator as well .
Instead recyclerview fails to update its height to wrap around both the view hence resulting in this incomplete view.

[image]

This is happening because the recyclerview was unable to update its height when scrolling hence making the view cut in half.

I have tried multiple ways to fix this like ,
Setting setHasFixedSize to false etc . But didnt seem to work

This is happening only sometimes.

The only viable solution now is to fix the recycler view height to a specific height so that it holds both the views.
But I want a more scalable and optimum solution if possible for this .

Is there any way to make recyclerview recalculate its height ?

Recyclerview Item view code.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_learn_item"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_width="134dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        />    

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/video_update_tv_guideline"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="195dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/video_update_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/iv_learn_item"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/iv_learn_item"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/video_update_tv_guideline"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dimen_11dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dimen_11dp"
        style="@style/content_update_pill"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Adapter code

```
                rvVideoPacks.layoutManager =
                    LinearLayoutManager(itemView.context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
                rvVideoPacks.setHasFixedSize(false)
                rvVideoPacks.itemAnimator = null
                rvVideoPacks.isNestedScrollingEnabled = true
                rvVideoPacks.adapter = videoPackAdapter
```

EDIT :

I have also tried to make the indicator invisible , but that just creates an extra space at the bottom , making it look bad.
I want the recyclerview to adjust its height accordingly.

Comment: You can use instead of GONE of the text indicator, use INVISIBLE to keep all lengths equal, this should resolve your problem

Comment: @MokhtarAbdelhalim yes that would solve the issue , but that would mean that the recycler view would have a an extra space even. This creates a bad visual experience in my app , Thats why I didnt use that.

Comment: The video indicator can be drawn outside the bounds of the RecyclerView (partly inside and the rest outside), but there may be an issue if the indicator can be clicked. This will introduce some additional space below the RecyclerView but not as much as the whole indicator height.

Comment: @Cheticamp I do not think thats a good solution , since there are other views below my recyclerview.

Comment: So, you want the views below the _RecyclerView_ to jump down when a taller view scrolls into view?

Comment: @Cheticamp no I want my recyclerview to adjust its height ( increase ) when taller views comes into the screen.

Comment: @SaneenKP are you able to solve this issue? facing the same issue in nested horizontal recyclerView

Answer (score 0):

One way to fix this issue is give fix height to main ConstraintLayout if possible for your layout.

Comment: Yes that is possible , and that is a solution . but its not scalable , If i get more views or my other layout changes , I would have to again change the height . 
This is not a solution , its a fix . I wanted to know if there was anything more optimum like something handled by recyclerview itself.
Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Hi a way is using ConstraintLayout as parent and child will be anything u want
like linearLayout or else

like this.

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

    android:id="@+id/myconstraint"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:paddingStart="24dp"
    android:paddingEnd="24dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:padding="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:id="@+id/relative"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"

        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"

        android:background="@drawable/custom_back_button"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">


    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgv_frcl_complet_elevels"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/pluto_success_1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/tv_complete_congrats"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/tv_winner_complete_levels"
        android:textColor="@color/duskYellow"
        android:textSize="26sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/relative"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/relative"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imgv_frcl_complet_elevels" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_messag_complete"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"

        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Beginner Mode"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/relative"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/relative"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_complete_congrats" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_complete_levels_continue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"

        android:layout_height="56dp"

        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/mode_selection_back"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_top"
        android:text="@string/btn_complete_continue_playing"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/relative"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/relative"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/relative"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_messag_complete" />

    <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
        android:id="@+id/lottie_win_levels"
        android:layout_width="0dp"

        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:lottie_loop="true" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Can you share the others design or where u inspired

source https://gist.github.com/rogergcc/557f51940dd400b35893ffe5bad04e59#file-dialog_complet_levels-xml